# Creating a matrix based on a function in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a symmetric matrix (dimension: 12,000 X 12,000) named A and I want to create another one based on a formula, which depends on the elements position. To explain:
I want to create the D matrix (based on the values from A) using the formula:

```
Dij = 1 - (aij/sqrt(aii*ajj))
```

A small example of A is:

```
A = matrix(c(1,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.5,1.1,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.5,1.2,0.5,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.2,1.2),ncol=5,nrow=5, byrow=T)
```

As I have a huge matrix, what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: What did you search/try so far before asking?

Comment: I can't immediately see a quick or mathematically elegant way to do this, so you'll likely be stuck with one of `apply`, `mapply`, or `sapply`. If you aren't comfortable with the `*apply` family of functions, either (a) this is a great time to dive in, or (b) `for` loops will likely work "just as well".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
1-cov2cor(A)

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
 [1,] 0.0000000 0.5232687 0.6348516 0.7000000 0.8174258
 [2,] 0.5232687 0.0000000 0.5648059 0.6186150 0.7388835
 [3,] 0.6348516 0.5648059 0.0000000 0.5435645 0.5000000
 [4,] 0.7000000 0.6186150 0.5435645 0.0000000 0.8174258
 [5,] 0.8174258 0.7388835 0.5000000 0.8174258 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 3):

`cov2cor` is the way to go, but you can exploit the fact that `aii` and `ajj` are always on the diagonal of your matrix.

```
1 - A/sqrt(outer(diag(A), diag(A), `*`))

#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.0000000 0.5232687 0.6348516 0.7000000 0.8174258
# [2,] 0.5232687 0.0000000 0.5648059 0.6186150 0.7388835
# [3,] 0.6348516 0.5648059 0.0000000 0.5435645 0.5000000
# [4,] 0.7000000 0.6186150 0.5435645 0.0000000 0.8174258
# [5,] 0.8174258 0.7388835 0.5000000 0.8174258 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vectorization of `R` to accomplish the task without any explicit loops:

```
B <- matrix(rep(diag(A), ncol(A)), ncol(A))
C <- matrix(rep(diag(A), ncol(A)), ncol(A), byrow= TRUE)
D <- 1 - (A/sqrt(B*C))

#which gives

D
# 
# [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.0000000 0.5232687 0.6348516 0.7000000 0.8174258
# [2,] 0.5232687 0.0000000 0.5648059 0.6186150 0.7388835
# [3,] 0.6348516 0.5648059 0.0000000 0.5435645 0.5000000
# [4,] 0.7000000 0.6186150 0.5435645 0.0000000 0.8174258
# [5,] 0.8174258 0.7388835 0.5000000 0.8174258 0.0000000
```

Comment: No need to preallocate `D`